# How to implement an interface to a sub-matrix in CUDA?

Tags: c++, matrix, cuda, matrix-multiplication, cublas

I have a wrapper class `CudaMatrix` that implements several cuBLAS operations, allowing me to call `m1.multiply(m2)` that runs the `sgemm` operation on the internal data pointers.

I would like to extend the class by operations on sub-matrices, something like

```
CudaMatrix a(100,100);
CudaMatrix b(100,100);
// fill a and b

int i=5, j=15;
CudaSubMatrix sa(a, i, j, i+10, j+10); // sa := a[5:15, 15:25]

i=50, j=60;
CudaSubMatrix sb(b, i, j, i+10, j+10); // sb := b[50:60, 60:70]    

CudaMatrix res;
res.copy(sa);
res.multiply(sb)  // res = sa*sb
```

In the last row, `multiply()` needs to operate on a sub-matrix `sb`, so the rows are not contiguous and I can't call the same `sgemm` operations as before.

How do I implement an efficient interface to sub-matrices that avoids copying data explicitly? Are there any open-source implementations that I can look for?

Comment: I don't understand the question. CUBLAS already has everything required to perform operations on sub-matrices without requiring additional interface code or wrappers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sub-matrices multiply may be performed using the ldx parameter of the API calls.

Indexing is described at the [1.1 DataLayout](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#introduction) section:

> #define IDX2C(i,j,ld) (((j)*(ld))+(i))

Then use the [cublasSgemm](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-gemm) for example with `lda` parameter equal to the number of lines

> the cuBLAS library uses column-major storage

of the original matrix, and `m`,`n`,`k` for the sub-matrices.

Note indexing might differ in fortran for C indexing scheme.

Hence what you really need is the size of your sub-matrix (col,rows), and the size of a column in the input matrix (its number of lines).